# Genric Translucent image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blur

I want an image of 320x80 size so that whenever I put this image above any image it will create a blur effect. Just like a translucent mirror. Below is the sample image of iPhone app.

Here the navigation bar is blurred and what happens there is that when I scroll down the content below this nav bar gets blurred.

Is this possible to create an image like this? Which can blur everything behind it at run time (what ever the content it has behind it, not static but dynamic)

P.S. I know how to blur an image but that will be static

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be an actual image? can you not do this with css?

Comment: I just want a blurred image probably with white color. So that when I place this image/png(first.png) on another image the portion below first.png looks blurred. I don't want to use css or other thing. There are two images one is normal and other is translucent one which make normal image blur

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a non-destructive and reusable blurred/frosted glass effect?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/how-to-create-a-non-destructive-and-reusable-blurred-frosted-glass-effect) and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25993/blur-a-transparent-image?rq=1 and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25755/how-to-create-blur-on-an-empty-layer-in-photoshop?lq=1 -- is this a class assignment or something? Seems we've had this same question many times the past week.

Comment: @Scott I have read that question. What I exactly need is an image which can blur any image below it. Is it possible to create such image ?

Comment: And moreover it's not my assignment because I'm not a graphics designer, I'm a programmer http://stackoverflow.com/users/468724/inder-kumar-rathore

Comment: Inder, you **obviously** have not read all the links I posted. iOS uses the method I posted in the third link.

Comment: As the duplicate question states, this is not possible.

Comment: To pile on here: the problem is you want a blur effect that responds to dynamic content under it. This MUST be done programatically.

Comment: Thanks @horatio.. I got the point that to blur anything you need to blur that actual thing. You can't have the separate png which will blur the other image. Also I was curious becuase in real life translucent mirror produces the same effect. You place translucent mirror above anything and that becomes blur.